# Unable to install bcrypt-ruby, blocks upgrade of devise, "Failed to build native gem extension"

Tags: ruby, devise, rubygems, bcrypt-ruby

I'm on Mac OSX 10.10.2. In attempting to upgrade devise from 2.1.2 to 2.2.8 (by updating the version in the Gemfile), `bundle install` attempts to install bcrypt 3.1.10 and crashes with this output:

```
        /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb
        creating Makefile

        make  clean

        make
        compiling bcrypt_ext.c
        make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Segmentation fault: 11

        make failed, exit code 2
```

I have attempted some fixes found in searching, such as:

```
`gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'´
```

(same error)

Download gem source from github (https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) and attempt to install from the local gemfile (same error).

Uninstall bcrypt-ruby with `gem uni bcrypt`, reinstalling with `gem i bcrypt-ruby --platform=ruby` (same error)

If I set user to root with `sudo su -`, I am able to run the install with the following output:

```
 root# gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'
 Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
 Successfully installed bcrypt-3.1.10
 Parsing documentation for bcrypt-3.1.10
 unable to convert "\xCA" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle, skipping
 1 gem installed
```

However, if I exit out of root, bundle install still fails.

Running rvm 1.25.3, ruby 1.9.3, gem 2.2.2, Bundler version 1.9.4, Xcode 6.3, Command Line Tools 6.3

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this worked:

- Updating RVM to head with `rvm get head`
- Uninstall rvm 1.9.3 with `rvm uninstall 1.9.3`
- Re-install rvm 1.9.3. Tried running `rvm install 1.9.3`, which advised to run `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551` instead. Did that.
- `rvm use 1.9.3`
- Reinstalled bundler with `gem install bundler`
- Now, finally `bundle install` works.

It seems likely that previous steps (particularly running updates on Xcode & Command Line Tools) have contributed to success.